# Can i rearange an array, the way i want it (switch index numbers no sorting)?

Tags: powershell

I want to make a selection list, to select an installed printer. But the default printer has to be on top of that list. How can i switch lets say index 5 of an array with index 0?

I know i can do this a lot of ways, but only want to know if it is possible to change index numbers of an array.

This is already working code:

```bsh
$Printers = Get-Printer
$DefaultPrinter = Get-WmiObject -Query " SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer WHERE Default=$true" | Select -Expand Name
$PrinterSelection = $Printers.Name
```

`$PrinterSelection` output: (Brother printer is default)

> Verzenden naar OneNote 16 
>   OneNote 
>   Microsoft XPS Document Writer 
>   Microsoft Print to PDF 
>   Fax 
>   Brother DCP-J4120DW Printer 
>   Adobe PDF

```bsh
$FirstPrinter = $PrinterSelection[0]
$DefaultPrinterNumber = [array]::indexof($PrinterSelection,$DefaultPrinter)
$PrinterSelection[0] = $DefaultPrinter
$PrinterSelection[$DefaultPrinterNumber] = $FirstPrinter
```

`$PrinterSelection` output:

> Brother DCP-J4120DW Printer 
>   OneNote 
>   Microsoft XPS Document Writer 
>   Microsoft Print to PDF 
>   Fax 
>   Verzenden naar OneNote 16 
>   Adobe PDF

Problem solved, but is there a cleaner way?
In normal steps:
Cut `$PrinterSelection[$DefaultPrinterNumber]` Insert `$PrinterSelection[0]` (not overwrite)

Comment: Why not sue the output of your `Get-WmiObject` call directly?  The two calls are getting the data from the same place (`Win32_Printer` class), even though the eventual output isn't identical.  Then you could simply sort by the `Default` property to get that particular printer to the 'top' of the list.

Comment: That's a possibility but i want to know more about array editing in powershell. But indeed a clean way, probably the cleanest option posible

Comment: *"probably the cleanest option posible"* - asking questions looking for the best, cleanest, fastest, etc technique are likely to get closed as 'primarily opinion based'.

Comment: `$PrinterSelection = Get-WmiObject -Query " SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer" | sort "Default" -Descending | Select -Expand Name` is working perfect. And you are right about that boxdog. I was more looking for a clean way to editing array's in powershell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Remove()` and `Insert()` methods of a generic list to do this. Generic lists are mutable. In this case, I'm typing the list items as strings.

```
$printerselection = $printers.name -as 'System.Collections.Generic.List[String]'
$printerselection.Remove($Defaultprinter)
$printerselection.Insert(0,$Defaultprinter)
```

The `-as` operator will change the type of your `$printers.name` output from array to **System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]** granting mutability and access to the methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can swap positions 0 and 5 like this:

```
$a[0],$a[5] = $a[5],$a[0]
```